# Código para validar un formulario con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

Tengo este formulario

```html
<form class="form">
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" title="Ingrese su nombre" placeholder="Su nombre">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="telefono" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Su telefono de contacto">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="email" type="text" id="email" title="Ingrese su email" placeholder="Su email" require>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <textarea name="mensaje" rows="5" id="mensaje" title="Comentarios" placeholder="Comentarios"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <button class="bottom">Enviar</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

este tiene diferentes estilos, lo que no se es como se valida este código en JavaScript, y que al yo dejar un campo vació me salga un alert, y que si todo esta bien me salga un mensaje que diga sus datos se han enviado con éxit

Comment: No has añadido código, creo que te has confundido

Comment: si lo añadí, pero no se porque no me aparece....si le doy editar el código esta

Comment: Añade tu codigo js

Comment: Es que no lo tengo porque no se como se hace.

Comment: Quizas ayudaria un poco si le pusieras `type='email'` y `type='tel'` a tus inputs, ayuda con las validaciones, tambien puedes asignarles `required` para asegurarte de que no se envien vacios.

Comment: Gracias a todos son lo máximo.....Creo que definitivamente voy a entrar a estudiar Ingeniería de sistemas. ES UN MUNDO MUY LINDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizas ayudaria un poco si le pusieras type='email' y type='tel' a tus inputs, ayuda con las validaciones, tambien puedes asignarles required para asegurarte de que no se envien vacios.

```html
<form class="form">
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="nombre" type="text" required id="nombre" title="Ingrese su nombre" placeholder="Su nombre">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="telefono" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" required id="telefono" placeholder="Su telefono de contacto">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="email" type="email" required id="email" title="Ingrese su email" placeholder="Su email">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <textarea name="mensaje" required rows="5" id="mensaje" title="Comentarios" placeholder="Comentarios"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <button class="bottom">Enviar</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Me parece que este acercamiento es mas apropiado, ya que si en `html` hay caracteristicas para resolver esto, deberian usarla.

Comment: Supongo que la OP tambien quiera un poco de validaciones mas especificas, aparte de las que soportan los browser

Comment: Notese que `pattern` en el `input tel`, es una regex que valida que sean numeros lo que se escriba en el.

Comment: No sólo que sean números, deben seguir un patrón definido de acuerdo al país. Por ejemplo, tanto (+598) 984838473 como +599 984838473 deben considerarse válidos en el caso de Uruguay.

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que probablemente más adelante quieras hacer más validaciones (que el nombre tenga una longitud mínima, que no esté compuesto únicamente por espacios, que el teléfono o el email tengan un formato correcto....)

Lo que deberías hacer es crear una función para validar estos datos en el evento click del botón y en función del resultado de estas validaciones mostrar los mensajes de error correspondientes o continuar con el envío del formulario:

```js
function validarFormulario(e){
  var error = false;
  var messages = '';
  var nombre = document.getElementsByName('nombre')[0].value;
  if (!nombre){
    messages+= 'Debe rellenar el campo nombre\n';
    error = true;
  }
  var telefono = document.getElementsByName('telefono')[0].value;
  if (!telefono){
    messages+= 'Debe rellenar el campo teléfono\n';
    error = true;
  }
  var email = document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value;
  if (!email) {
    messages+= 'Debe rellenar el campo email\n';
    error = true;
  }
  var comentarios = document.getElementsByName('mensaje')[0].value;
  if (!comentarios) {
    messages+= 'Debe rellenar el campo comentarios\n';
    error = true;
  }
  var errorDiv = document.querySelector('.errorMessages');
  errorDiv.innerText = messages;
  if (error) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return !error;
}

var btnEnviar = document.querySelector('.bottom');
btnEnviar.addEventListener('click', validarFormulario);
```

```css
.errorMessages{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" title="Ingrese su nombre" placeholder="Su nombre">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="telefono" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Su telefono de contacto">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="email" type="text" id="email" title="Ingrese su email" placeholder="Su email" require>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <textarea name="mensaje" rows="5" id="mensaje" title="Comentarios" placeholder="Comentarios"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input type="submit" class="bottom" value= "Enviar"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<div class="errorMessages"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Aparte de lo que te dicen, deberías aprovechar HTML5 para usar validaciones ya integradas, como es el caso de email y usar propias por medio de expresiones regulares directamente en el HTML mediante el atributo `pattern`.

**Ejemplo**

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 80%;
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #555;
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

input, textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05) inset;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <h2>Contáctenos</h2>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Su nombre" required pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" title="El nombre debe ser alpha">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="telefono" type="tel" id="telefono" placeholder="Su telefono de contacto" required title="No es un teléfono válido" pattern="^[\+\d]+">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <input name="email" type="email" id="email" title="Ingrese su email" placeholder="Su email" required title="El formato es inválido">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <textarea name="mensaje" rows="5" id="mensaje" title="Comentarios" placeholder="Comentarios" required></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content-input">
  <div class="input">
   <button class="bottom">Enviar</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe una validación por defecto de html5 (required). Creo que intentaste usarla porque veo un **require** embebido en tu codido. Para que funcione esta validación la palabra correcta es **required** y es necesario usar un **input** tipo **"submit"**. Aquí te dejo la muestra. Estabas muy cerca, solo te falto estos tips. Espero que te sirva. 
Saludos.

```js
function enviar(e) {
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Datos enviados");
  e.target.reset();
}
```

```html
<form class="form" onsubmit="enviar(event)">
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" title="Ingrese su nombre" placeholder="Su nombre" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <input name="telefono" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Su telefono de contacto" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email" title="Ingrese su email" placeholder="Su email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <textarea name="mensaje" rows="5" id="mensaje" title="Comentarios" placeholder="Comentarios" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias.....  :)

Comment: De nada. Agregue nuevas cosas que tal vez te sirvan como: prevenir recargar la pagina al presionar submit y limpiar el formulario. Pruébalo  y me comentas :D

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputs = $("#myfrom").serializeArray();
```

Donde te obtiene el nombre de tus inputs y su valor, por ende los invalidos tendrán el valor '',

```
const InvalidInputs = inputs.filter(obj => obj.value === '')
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

La solución a tu problema es recorrer todos los campos `input` comprobando que no estén vacíos:

```js
function validarInputs() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var correcto = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].innerHTML === "" || inputs[i].innerHTML === null) {
      correcto = false;
    }
  }
  return correcto;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" title="Ingrese su nombre" placeholder="Su nombre">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <input name="telefono" type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Su telefono de contacto">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email" title="Ingrese su email" placeholder="Su email" require>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <textarea name="mensaje" rows="5" id="mensaje" title="Comentarios" placeholder="Comentarios"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-input">
    <div class="input">
      <button class="bottom" onclick="validarInputs()">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Lo único que tienes que hacer a partir de ahí es que, dependiendo del valor de `correcto`, seguir en tu formulario o no.

Comment: con anyadirle la propiedad `required` valida que no esten vacios, no tienes que anyidir mas codigo para eso

Comment: el codigo ni siquiera corria, trata de probar la respuestas antes de postearlas